# How to get the lat & lng as separate variables from mapCenter

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the map center, and comes as a Floating Point number.

How can I get it as 2 separated variables like this:

```
var lat = ...

var lng = ...
```

I have the float:

```
var NewMapCenter = map.getCenter();
```

I tried to pass the float `toWords(x)` but didn't work

I tried to subtract the `(,)` and `split` it, but didn't work

```
var latlngStr = (StrNewMapCenter.substr(1, (StrNewMapCenter.length-1))).split(",",2);
var NewMapCenter = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
```

I tried, this but comes as an event, but I need it without needing to click.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var myLatLng = event.latlng;
    var Newlat = position.coords.latitude;
    var Newlng = position.coords.longitude;
}
```

Thanks
Sebastian

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var NewMapCenter = map.getCenter();
```

will give you LatLng object, so you can call

```
var latitude = NewMapCenter.lat();
var longitude = NewMapCenter.lng();
```

Comment: @Sebastian - if this is the right answer, you can mark it as correct by clicking the checkbox to the left of it. That'll close the question and give some extra rep to the person answering.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know, I just did it ;o) @nrabinowitz